# how do i fix "HTML5 Audio pool exhausted, returning potentially locked audio object." i have tried add sound

Tags: howler.js

this is my code it creates a new howl called sound, which defines some variables, than it plays a random song from a list of songs than after it ends, it ends the sound, unloads it and plays a different song from the list after it unloads and stops

```
function PlaySong(Choice, Songs) {
    var Choice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16);
    var sound = new Howl({

        src: [Songs[Choice]],
        html5: true,
        onend: function () {
            sound.stop();
            sound.unload();
            PlaySong(Choice, Songs)
        }
    });

    sound.play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you could program it without Howler - just using the HTML5 audio tag. (I used Howler myself, but it's quite complex and seemed to have issues with not properly unloading played audio files. Then I switched to plain HTML5 audio, which solved my problems.)

```
<audio id="audio"></audio>
<input type="button" onclick="playNextSong()" value="Play" />
<script>
    const songs = ['file1.mp3', 'file2.mp3', 'file3.mp3'];

    const playNextSong = () => {
        const audioTag = document.getElementById("audio");
        audioTag.src = songs[Math.floor(Math.random() * songs.length)];
        audioTag.play();
        audioTag.onended = playNextSong;
    }
</script>
```

Please note, that the initial play has to be triggered by a user action (e.g. button click). Browser won't let you play anything until one such event occurred (to prevent noisy ads, I guess). The typical solution would be having an "enter" button at the beginning of your webapp, which plays 1 second of a silent mp3 just to enable sound playback.

I don't know Blazor webassembly, so you will have to see how to translate that.

Comment: i tried this, still same error, i even tried clearing all my data.

Comment: Why do you need howler if all you want to do is play a playlist of songs? HTML5-Audio is sufficient for that. Howler is useful, when you're programming a game with lots of little sound effects or a mixing software with multiple audio channels.

Comment: How could I go about doing that? (Note that I am not using traditional html and JavaScript, I’m using something Blazor webassembly)

Comment: I updated the solution, now it's an example on how to use HTML5 audio tag.